# Some problems in model window

Tags: livecode

I create a model window(new Substack) for find a text in scrolling field. But it's not working i am using the following code

the following code calls the modal window

```
on mouseUp
modal stack "sub"
end mouseUp
```

The following code for finding a string in Scrolling field

```
on mouseUp
     if field "EE" is empty  then
      answer "Please enter the filename" with "Ok"
   end if
   if field "EE" is not empty  then
      put the text of field "EE" into xx
      --answer xx
       repeat for each word myword in fld "MytextField"
if  fld "MytextField" contains xx then find xx in fld "MytextField"
           exit to top
  end repeat
      end if
end mouseUp
```

Here "MytextField" is in main stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't explain what "not working" means, but most likely because stack "sub" is a different stack, you need to use an explicit reference for the field:

```
field "EE" of stack "myMainStack"
```

Another option is to set the defaultStack property to the name of your main stack, so you don't need to use explicit object references:

```
set the defaultStack to "myMainStack"
if field "EE" is empty then...
```

Remember to change the defaultStack back to your substack if you ever need to refer to an object in the substack.

Comment: Thank you @ Scott Rossi My problem is I create a Substack and place  one text field and one button. Button for find a string in main stack but it's not working

Comment: where I insert field code                                                                                            field "EE" of stack "myMainStack"

Comment: Instead of writing: if field "EE" is empty then...   Write this: if field "EE" of stack "myMainStack" is empty then...

Answer (score 0):

You also don't need the repeat loop or the test for "contains". The loop isn't doing anything. All you need is

```
find xx in field "MytextField"
```

If the text isn't there the result will be "not found", otherwise the text will be boxed.

```
   put the text of field "EE" into xx
   if xx is not empty then
       find xx in field "MytextField"                                          
      if the result is not empty then
         answer the result 
      end if
    end if
```